# Where does the square come from in this application of the Divergence Theorem?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, divergence-theorem

This is an equation in a well known paper, which I cannot figure out: specifically, where does the 2nd power come from in the second integral?

[image: Screenshot of the original paper]

Here $k_1$ is a scalar function of $c$, and $c$ is a scalar function of its location in space: $c(\mathbf{x})$.

This appears to be done using integration by parts:

$$
\int u dv = uv - \int v du
$$

where in this case:

$$
u = k_1
$$
$$
du = dk_1/dc
$$
$$
dv = \nabla^2 c
$$
$$
v = \nabla c
$$

which results in:

$$
\int_V (k_1 \nabla^2 c) dV = \int_S (k_1 \nabla c \cdot n) dS - \int_V \frac{dk_1}{dc} \nabla c\ dV
$$

What am I missing? A similar result can be achieved using the divergence theorem, but again, I end up missing the: $(\nabla c)^2$.

I'll note that this cannot be a typo in the paper, and given how well established this paper and it's results are, I think it's overwhelmingly likely that I'm misunderstanding something basic about the math here.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: “A well known paper” is rather useless information. Why not say *which* paper it is?

Comment: (Also note that it's the Greek letter $\kappa$ (kappa), not the Latin letter $k$.)

Comment: I didn't think it added much.  If you're curious it's "Free Energy of a Nonuniform System." by Cahn and Hilliard, 1957.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently $\kappa_1$ is a function of $c$. Then the divergence of $\kappa_1 \nabla c$ is
$$
\nabla \kappa_1 \cdot \nabla c + \kappa_1 \nabla^2 c,
$$
where the chain rule says that
$$
\nabla \kappa_1 = \frac{d\kappa_1}{dc} \nabla c
,
$$
so that
$$
\nabla \cdot (\kappa_1 \nabla c) = \frac{d\kappa_1}{dc} \nabla c \cdot \nabla c + \kappa_1 \nabla^2 c
,
$$
and the result follows from the divergence theorem.

Comment: Thanks! That solves the mystery.  I forgot to apply the chain rule when evaluating $\grad k_1$.